# How to align \thanks and \footnote?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes

How do I align `\footnote` and `\thanks` in LaTeX? For example, the code below does not align the <sup>1</sup> of `\thanks` and <sup>a</sup> of `\footnote`. The `.sty` file can be downloaded here: [`spconf`](https://2022.ieeeicassp.org/papers/PaperFormat/spconf.sty).

```
% Template for ICASSP-2021 paper; to be used with:
%          spconf.sty  - ICASSP/ICIP LaTeX style file, and
%          IEEEbib.bst - IEEE bibliography style file.
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatother

% Title.
% ------
\title{Title}

% Single address.
% ---------------
\name{Author1 and Author2$^{1}$% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}${\tt\small \{abc, abc\}}}%
}
\address{Department, XYZ \\ XYZ}

\begin{document}
%\ninept
%
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} Abstract. \footnote{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Human Pose Forecasting
\end{keywords}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\thanks` footnote is just set without any number; you manually provide this number, but it is considered as part of the footnote text. So we can `\llap` (a `l`eft over`lap`) this manually-supplied number:

[image]

```
% Template for ICASSP-2021 paper; to be used with:
%          spconf.sty  - ICASSP/ICIP LaTeX style file, and
%          IEEEbib.bst - IEEE bibliography style file.
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spconf}% https://2022.ieeeicassp.org/papers/PaperFormat/spconf.sty

\title{Title}

\name{%
  Author1 and Author2\textsuperscript{\upshape 1}%
  % \llap the footnote number to align with other footnote numbers
  \thanks{\llap{\textsuperscript{1}}{\ttfamily\footnotesize \{abc, abc\}}}% 
}
\address{Department, XYZ \\ XYZ}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}%
  Abstract.\footnote{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
some relavent set of keywords
\end{keywords}

\end{document}
```